# How to build dynamic query by binding parameters in node.js-sql?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using `nodejs-mysql` module to do query in node.js recently, and in my working case I could only use the parameter-binding syntax like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ?
```

Now I want to build dynamic sql with these `?` OR `??` parameters. Assume that I have 2 conditions(`name` and `age`) which either of them could be null (if user doesn't provide it),
So I want to build MySQL in 3 cases:

1. only `name=Bob`: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'Bob'`
2. only `age=40`: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE age > 40`
3. both: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = 'Bob' AND age > 40`

I know it's easy if you build the query on your own, but how can I achieve it when using placeholders which can only bind field or values ?

In document of `nodejs-mysql`, placeholder `?` only stands for values and `??` stands for fields:

- https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#escaping-query-values
- https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/#escaping-query-identifiers

My first thinking of solution is to insert query piece by using these placeholders, but it comes to failure because both `?` and `??` will escape my query piece, and my query will be executed incorrectly.

My code so far is as below, which I'm defenitly sure it's not correct because query piece has been escaped:

```
// achieve paramters from url request
var condition = {};
if(params.name)condition["name"] = ["LIKE", "%" + params.name + "%"];
if(params.age)condition["age"] = parseInt(params.age, 10);

//build query
var sqlPiece = buildQuery(condition);

//try to replace ? with query
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ?';

connection.query(sql, sqlPiece, function(err, results) {
  // do things
});

// my own query build function to proceed conditions
function buildQuery(condition) {
  var conditionArray = [];
  for(var field in condition){
    var con = condition[field];
    if(con !== undefined){
      field = arguments[1] ? arguments[1] + "." + field : field;
      var subCondition;
      if(con instanceof Array) {
        subCondition = field + " " + con[0] + " " + wrapString(con[1]);
      }else{
        subCondition = field + " = " + wrapString(con);
      }
      conditionArray.push(subCondition);
    }
  }
  return conditionArray.length > 0 ? conditionArray.join(" AND ") : "1";
}

//wrap string value
function wrapString(value){
  return typeof value === "string" ? "'" + value + "'" : value;
}
```

So is there any way I can fix this problem?

### Update

Thanks to Jordan's Offer, it's working, but :

I know building query by string concat is very good, but in my case I can't use that, because I'm using some **middleware** or handle mysql and controller, so what I can do is to define **interface**, which is a sql string with placeholders. So, the interface string is predefined before, and I can't modify it during my controller function.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have so far.

Answer (score 30):

You're off to a really good start, but you may have been overthinking it a bit. The trick is to build a query with placeholders (`?`) as a string and simultaneously build an array of values.

So, if you have `params = { name: 'foo', age: 40 }`, you want to build the following objects:

```
where = 'name LIKE ? AND age = ?';
values = [ '%foo%', 40 ];
```

If you only have `{ name: 'foo' }`, you'll build these instead:

```
where = 'name LIKE ?';
values = [ '%foo%' ];
```

Either way, you can use those objects directly in the `query` method, i.e.:

```
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ' + where;
connection.query(sql, values, function...);
```

How do we build those objects, then? In fact, the code is really similar to your `buildQuery` function, but less complex.

```
function buildConditions(params) {
  var conditions = [];
  var values = [];
  var conditionsStr;

  if (typeof params.name !== 'undefined') {
    conditions.push("name LIKE ?");
    values.push("%" + params.name + "%");
  }

  if (typeof params.age !== 'undefined') {
    conditions.push("age = ?");
    values.push(parseInt(params.age));
  }

  return {
    where: conditions.length ?
             conditions.join(' AND ') : '1',
    values: values
  };
}

var conditions = buildConditions(params);
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ' + conditions.where;

connection.query(sql, conditions.values, function(err, results) {
  // do things
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I know building query by string concat is very good, but in my case I can't use that, cause I'm using some middleware ot handle mysql and controller, so what I can do is to define "interface", which is sql string with placeholders. So, the interface string is predefined before, and I can't modify it during my controller function.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "interface." Can you show some code? node-mysql's placeholders are for escaping fields and values, and you're not going to be able to make them work for larger SQL strings. If you want similar functionality but without escaping, I suggest using an sprintf implementation like [sprintf.js](https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js).

Comment: Yes I used a middleware, and what I can do is to define a .json file which describe the interfaces, like : `sql: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...?...??", It's fixed and will be loaded when it's initialing, so I can's insert some sql pieces

Answer (score 1):

For Inserting into MYSQL like DB:

```
function generateInsertQuery(data, tableName) {
    let part1 = `INSERT INTO ${tableName} (`;
    let part2 = ")",
        part3 = "VALUES (",
        part4 = ")";
    let tableKeys = "",
        tableValues = "";
    for (let key in data) {
        tableKeys += `${key},`;
        tableValues += `'${data[key]}',`
    }

    tableKeys = tableKeys.slice(0, -1);
    tableValues = tableValues.slice(0, -1);
    let query = `${part1}${tableKeys}${part2} ${part3}${tableValues}${part4}`;
    return query;
}

generateInsertQuery({name: "Sam", tel: 09090909, email: "address@domain.com"}, "Person")
```

**Output:**

```
INSERT INTO Person (name,tel,email) VALUES ('Sam','9090909','address@domain.com');
```

Code Snippet for Update query:

```
function generateUpdateQuery(data, tableName, clauseKey, clauseValue) {
    let part1 = `UPDATE ${tableName} SET`;
    let part2 = `WHERE ${clauseKey} = ${clauseValue};`; //Add any number of filter clause statements here
    let updateString = "";
    for (let key in data) {
        updateString += `${key} = '${data[key]}',`;
    }
    updateString = updateString.slice(0, -1);
    let query = `${part1} ${updateString} ${part2}`;
    return query;
}

generateUpdateQuery({
    name: "Tanjiro",
    tel: 77777777,
    email: "tanjiro@demonslayer.com"
}, "Person", "ID", 111);
```

Output:

```
UPDATE Person SET name = 'Tanjiro',tel = '77777777',email = 'tanjiro@demonslayer.com' WHERE ID = 111;
```

Answer (score 0):

I modify your code @Jordan-Running

```js
describe("Test generateFilterQuery", () => {
    
    it("Query filter with params", () => {

        let params = []

        params.push(Query.generateParams("title", "%_%", "Coding"))
        params.push(Query.generateParams("published", "=", true))

        console.log(Query.generateFilterQuery(params))

    });

});
```

```js
const qInclude = require('./QueryInclude');

exports.generateParams = (name, eq, value) => {
    return {
        name: name,
        eq: eq, // %_%, %_, _%, =, >, <, !=,
        value: value
    }
}

exports.generateFilterQuery = (params) => {
    let conditions, values = []
    let conditionsStr;

    if (params.length == 0) {
        return false
    }

    [conditions, values] = qInclude.queryCondition(params)

    let build = {
        where: conditions.length ?
                conditions.join(' AND ') : '1',
        values: values
    };

    let query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ' + build.where;
    return [query, build.values]
}
```

```js
exports.queryCondition = (params) => {
    var conditions = [];
    var values = [];

    params.forEach(item => {
        switch (item.eq) {
            case '=': {
                conditions.push(item.name + " = ?");
                values.push(item.value);
                break; 
            }
            case '!=': {
                conditions.push(item.name + " != ?");
                values.push(item.value);
                break; 
            }
            case '<': {
                conditions.push(item.name + " < ?");
                values.push(item.value);
                break; 
            }
            case '>': {
                conditions.push(item.name + " > ?");
                values.push(item.value);
                break; 
            }
            case '%_%': {
                conditions.push(item.name + " LIKE ?");
                values.push("%" + item.value + "%");
                break; 
            }
            case '%_': {
                conditions.push(item.name + " LIKE ?");
                values.push("%" + item.value);
                break; 
            }
            case '_%': {
                conditions.push(item.name + " LIKE ?");
                values.push(item.value + "%");
                break; 
            }
        }
    });

    return [conditions, values]
}
```