# What is wrong with this method for updating multiple rows dynamically?

Tags: javascript, sql, mysql, node.js

```js
exports.createTaskDataForNewDay = async function(values) {
  try {
    console.log("values", JSON.stringify(values))
    let pool = await CreatePool() //[timestamp , requiredTimes , reward , difficulty ,taskId , uid , csn]
    let query = "update userTaskData set timestamp = ?,requiredTimes=?,timesCompleted=0,reward=?,difficulty=?,state=1,taskId=?,replacedF=0,replacedC=0 where uid =? and suitCase = ?"
    let resp = await pool.query(query, [values])
    if (resp.changedRows > 0) {
      return resp
    } else return {
      code: 400,
      mesage: "Could not insert data ! please try again or check syntax"
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    return {
      code: 500,
      message: error.message
    }
  }
}
```

the 'values' being passed to the function is an array of arrays . each element holding the place holder data for different rows that i want to update .
but i getan error that is parsing error - something wrong with syntax and the query that is logged is -

```
sql: `update userTaskData set timestamp = (1686124176992, 1, '{\\"t\\":\\"c\\",\\"v\\":1000}', 1, 't1', '21GGZzSudOdUjKXcbVQHtFtTK772', 1), (1686124176992, 3, '{\\"t\\":\\"g\\",\\"v\\":10}', 1, 't9', '21GGZzSudOdUjKXcbVQHtFtTK772', 1), (1686124176992, 5, '{\\"t\\":\\"c\\",\\"v\\":4000}', 2, 't17', '21GGZzSudOdUjKXcbVQHtFtTK772', 1), (1686124176992, 3, '{\\"t\\":\\"c\\",\\"v\\":1000}', 3, 't21', '21GGZzSudOdUjKXcbVQHtFtTK772', 1),requiredTimes=?,timesCompleted=0,reward=?,difficulty=?,state=1,taskId=?,replacedF=0,replacedC=0 where uid =? and suitCase = ?
```

It is placing all the elements in the first place holder. Where as it is working fine for the insert queries .
please tell me what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mysqljs/mysql` module does not support bulk records via `objects` or `arrays` for the `UPDATE` method in the same way you are familiar with for the `INSERT` method. What you are imagining is not even a native feature in MySQL [and at best can only be accomplished through `CASE` switching if you want to use the actual `UPDATE` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35726910/bulk-update-mysql-with-where-statement).

That leaves you with 2 options:

**Option 1**

As long as your table and the data you provide for the update contain a unique key, you can use `INSERT INTO table_name SET ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE …`

**Option 2**

If you don't have unique keyed fields and corresponding values in your query for a given table, you will have to build the query by iterating through your entries such that you end up with a string collection of however many `UPDATE` queries you will have - or - by building a query that leverages `CASE` conditions.

You can see some examples here: [How to create dynamic insert statement on the basis of POST body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57045121/how-to-create-dynamic-insert-statement-on-the-basis-of-post-body/57146920#57146920)

Comment: INSERT INTO table_name SET ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE … this worked the best for me . Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps 'values', being already an array, does not need to be wrapped in another array. You can pass it directly as follows:

let resp = await pool.query(query, values);