# How to pass parameter to mssql query in node js

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am changing my application's database from MySQL to MSSQL. I send parameters like below for MySQL database.

```
var sql = require('./db.js');
sql.query("select * from table where field1 = ? or field2 = ? ", [field1val, field2val], function (error, results) {
   if(error){
       //handle error
   }
   else{
      //handle the results
   } 
}
```

How to do this in MSSQL or is it even possible to do this way? (I am using `mssql` module).

The stored procedure is the only way to achieve it? If so, how to do that in Nodejs mssql module?

What is the best practice to run a query in SQL server if we can't send parameter (which escapes the string in mysql automatically)?

Comment: Please share your db.js script, so we will know what's happening in your sql.query function

Comment: sql.query("select * from table where field1 = "+field1val+" or field2 = "+field2val, function (error, results) {

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822891/how-to-build-dynamic-query-by-binding-parameters-in-node-js-sql

Answer (score 15):

I do parameterized SQL queries like this:

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var myFirstInput = "foo bar";
var mySecondInput = "hello world";

sql.input('inputField1', sql.VarChar, myFirstInput);
sql.input('inputField2', sql.VarChar, mySecondInput);

sql.query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 = @inputField1 OR field2 = @inputField2")
.then(function(results)
{
    //do whatever you want with the results
    console.log(results)
})
.catch(function(error)
{
   //do whatever when you get an error
   console.log(error)
})
```

What happens here is that the `sql.input('inputField1', sql.VarChar, myFirstInput)` will change out the `@inputField1` with the variable named `myFirstInput`. Same thing will happen for `@inputField2` with `mySecondInput`.

This will help it from SQL injections

Comment: Do the inputs get "reset" after each query?

Comment: @workwise as long as you assign 'myFirstInput' and 'mySecondInput' with different variables every time you query, then yes the inputs would have a different value every time the function is called.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this by installing the [tsqltring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsqlstring). The changes to the code looks like below. I format the string using parameters first, then use it in the `sql.query`.

Changed this

```
sql.query("select * from users where id = 1",  function (error, uresults) {}
```

To this

```
var sqlQry = SqlString.format('select * from users where id = ?',['1']);
sql.query(sqlQry,  function (error, uresults) {}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var sql = require('./db.js');
sql.query(`select * from table where field1 = ${field1val} or field2 = ${field2val}`, function (error, results) {
   if(error){
       //handle error
   }
   else{
      //handle the results
   } 
}
```

I think, it works for you :)

Comment: Careful with sql injection.

Comment: mssql does provide a tagged template approach that they claim guards against sql injection: https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#es6-tagged-template-literals  (though to be clear, this example doesn't use it)

Comment: +1 to **ES6 Tagged template literals** if we can trust [node-mssql documentation](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#es6-tagged-template-literals)

Comment: I can confirm literals are NOT sanitized. Tested this with my implementation (latest circa 2024) and the sql injection goes right through.

Answer (score -5):

You can use try like this

```
var id = 1234

var query = (SQL
            `SELECT fname, lname, email
             FROM users
             WHERE id = ${id}`
            )

var sql = require('./db.js');
sql.query("select * from table where field1 = ${field1val} or field2 = ${field2val} ", [field1val, field2val], function (error, results) {
   if(error){
       //handle error
   }
   else{
      //handle the results
   } 
}
```