# Apostrophe in textarea Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sql-server

I create a sort of a company forum. Users can create post to share an information. To do so and at the moment, they complete a form with a basic textarea. My problem is that when they write a word with an apostrophe, the code interpret the apostrophe as single quote and it create en exception. I show you the code and an exemple below.

Html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="admin">
      <div v-if="seenNews" id="news">
        <div class="form">
          <h4>Create a post</h4>
          <form class="newPost" action="/newPost" method="POST">
            <label id="titleLabel" for="titleInput">Title : </label>
            <input type="text" id="titleInput" name="titleInput" required>
            <label id="contentLabel" for="contentInput">Content : </label>
            <textarea id="contentInput" name="contentInput" cols="40" rows="5" required></textarea>
            <button type="submit">Create</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Back-end javascript :

app.js

```
const Server = require('./server/Server');
const express = require('express');
const DAO = require('./server/DAO');

const server = new Server();
server.start();

const dao = new DAO();
dao.connect();

server.app.post("/newPost", function(req, res) {
    try {
        dao.newPost(req.body.titleInput, req.body.contentInput).then(value => {
                res.redirect('/Admin');
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})
```

DAO.js

```
const sql = require('mssql');

class DAO {
    constructor() {
        this.sqlConfig = {
            user: 'username',
            password: 'password',
            server: 'SERVER',
            port:port,
            database: 'DB',
            options: {
                enableArithAbort: false,
                encrypt:false
            }
        }
    }

    async newPost(title, content) {
        try {
            let req = 'INSERT INTO DB.dbo.[Table] (title, content) VALUES (\''+title+'\',\''+content+'\')';
            console.log(req);
            await sql.query(req).then(value => {
                return true;
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

As exemple, if a user create a post with this content : `Ms. Smith's keys are at the reception desk`, I would have this in console :

```
RequestError: Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.
```

Maybe if I create a function to find en encode the character it can fix it, but I don't see how I can do so.

Comment: And welcome to your intro into sql injection attacks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58851859/14104

Comment: As @epascarello pointed out, you should prevent injection security issue : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection . Someone could download/delete your entire database ...

Comment: I will take care of that, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I finally use the JS function replace() to replace simple quote in my string by two simple quote. `''` is the equivalent of js `\'` in sql server.

`'INSERT INTO PROFACE.dbo.[Posts] (title, content) VALUES (\''+title.replace(/'/gi,"''")+'\',\''+content.replace(/'/gi,"''")+'\')'`