# putting vars in sql query

Tags: mysql, node.js

New to Node development.

How do you put a variable in a sql query for the VALUES part. Here is what I have. Let me know if it will work.

```
  let email = req.body.email;
  let number = req.body.number;

  var sql = "INSERT INTO userdata (email, number) VALUES (email, number)";
```

Thanks

Also, second question. is there anyway I can check if a record already exists with the same email or number within the one sql statement.

Comment: `var sql = \`INSERT INTO userdata (email, number) VALUES (${email}, ${number})\`;`, but that is really not the right way to do it because it will break if `email` or `number` contains special characters, and is open to SQL injection attacks. The right way is with [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851653/how-to-pass-parameter-to-mssql-query-in-node-js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values), You should to use parametrized query like:

```
const email = req.body.email;
const number = req.body.number;

const sql = "INSERT INTO userdata (email, number) VALUES (?, ?)";

connection.query(sql, [ email, number ], 

    function (err, results) {

    }
);
```

About second question: If you want to your table will have unique records fro each email/number pair you should to add unique index based on those fields.