# NodeJs / SQL Server - Error making post request

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I cannot insert data into a SQL Server database.

The error returned is this:

> The name "Desconto" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

My code:

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  sql.connect(config, error => {
    const request = new sql.Request();
      request.query(
        `INSERT INTO [dbo].[EventoCob](
        nom_evento, nom_everes, cod_tipoeve,
        cod_grupoeve, cod_conta, log_parcela, log_exibirnoboleto, des_unidade, num_qtd,
        val_unitario, dat_cadastro, nom_usercadastro, dat_ultalteracao, nom_userultalteracao,
        log_eventodesconto, log_eventojuros, log_impcontrextcur, log_ativo, log_exibeweb
        ) VALUES (
          ${req.body.nom_evento}, 
          ${req.body.nom_everes}, 
          ${req.body.cod_tipoeve},
          ${req.body.cod_grupoeve},
          ${req.body.cod_conta},
          ${req.body.log_parcela},
          ${req.body.log_exibirnoboleto},
          ${req.body.des_unidade},
          ${req.body.num_qtd},
          ${req.body.val_unitario},
          ${req.body.dat_cadastro},
          ${req.body.nom_usercadastro},
          ${req.body.dat_ultalteracao},
          ${req.body.nom_userultalteracao},
          ${req.body.log_eventodesconto},
          ${req.body.log_eventojuros},
          ${req.body.log_impcontrextcur},
          ${req.body.log_ativo},
          ${req.body.log_exibeweb}
        )`,
        (error, result, fields) => {
          if(error) {
            res.status(500).send({error: error})
          } else {
            const response = {
              message: 'Cadastrado com sucesso',
              resultado: {
                nom_evento: req.body.nom_evento
              }
            }
            res.status(201).send(response);
          }
        }
      )
    });
});
```

Comment: My guess is `VALUES (${req.body.nom_evento},` becomes `VALUES (DESCONTO,` when it should become `VALUES ('DESCONTO',`. Does node.js not have a better way to parameterize statements that doesn't require manually handling string delimiters (and therefore also having to escape any string delimiters _in the value_)? Or troubleshoot by printing the statement instead of executing it?

Comment: Eu tentei usar "?", mas não funciona como no mysql.

Comment: SO is an **English-only** site - please respect the [rules of the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/205114), and translate your question (including title!) into English, or else post it on [pt.so]

Comment: No, you shouldn't be using `?` either. See if [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58851859/61305) helps.

Comment: I wrapped the parameters like this "${}". The error still persists.
I will try to do as in the examples.

Comment: `VALUES("DESCONTO",` is still going to be trying to find a _column_ named `DESCONTO`. You need to figure out how to make it `VALUES('DESCONTO',`. Maybe with `'${}'` but that is still a not-so-optimal way of passing in parameters (because what happens with `O'Brien`?).

Comment: Right! It worked.
I understand it's not the safest way to do this. Is there any way to simplify sql.input(), so as not to repeat this over and over again?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't worry about repeating `sql.input()`, if you feel it's repetitive it's probably only because all the parameters are the same type, when you have other types like datetime and int...