# SQL Injection mssql Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, sql-injection

I'm trying to prevent an SQL Injection in my Node.js Backend. I'm using the mssql package, i was doing some tests and i found that if in a parameter there's the character **'** the query doesn't work (obviously).

```
sql.connect(sqlConfig, function (err) {
    str_query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE notes= '+req.query.notes+'';
    if (err) console.log(err);
       
    var request = new sql.Request();

    // query to the database and get the records
    request.query(str_query, function (err, recordset) {
    //here do things 

}
```

How i can prevent this ?

Comment: Use parametrisation. **Always** use parametrisation.

Comment: I don't know anything about node.js, but usually this is done by using parameters in stead of building the query

Comment: Doesn't work anymore in the new versione the request.input()

Comment: @Larnu I know the question is how to use paramter in mssql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass parameter to mssql query in node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851653/how-to-pass-parameter-to-mssql-query-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but here's how I would do it.

Here's a bit of information about what's going on from google.

> Parameterized queries force the developer to first define all the SQL code, and then pass in each parameter to the query later. This coding style allows the database to distinguish between code and data, regardless of what user input is supplied.

```
sql.connect(sqlConfig, function (err) {
    str_query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE notes=?';
    if (err) console.log(err);
       
    var request = new sql.Request();

    // query to the database and get the records
    request.query(str_query, [req.query.notes] , function (err, recordset) {
    //here do things 

}
```