# How can I return data from my MySQL database using a specific ID endpoint in my Node.js REST API?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Is it possible to return data from my database using a specific id endpoint "https://../profiles/1" with nodeJS?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
app.get('/profiles/:userids', function (req, res) {
   let user_id = req.query.user_id;
    con.connect(function(err) {
        con.query("SELECT * FROM db2.Profiles WHERE id = ", function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) {
                res.json({error: err});
                return;
            }
            res.json({success: 'get call succeed!', url: req.url, body: result})
        });
   });
});
```

What I want to do is be able to use https://../profiles/1 will display only data in id 1 from my database, https://../profiles/2 will display data in id 2 and so forth.
The link I use to test is from my AWS amplify project using API gateway.

What I tried so far:
`"SELECT * FROM db2.Profiles WHERE id = ?"`
`"SELECT * FROM db2.Profiles WHERE id ? "`

Comment: Current code seems incomplete, Let me know if this works for you: https://pastebin.com/X96Ktw1b

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_where.asp   // you didn't inject your parameter ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass parameter to mssql query in node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58851653/how-to-pass-parameter-to-mssql-query-in-node-js)

Comment: check if you are reading your parameter correctly. `req.params['userids']`