# How do I dynamically add where conditions?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

How do I make a dynamic query without SQL injection in n=Node.js SQL Server?

I used this query to prevent SQL injection.

```
const conn = await pool;
conn.query`select * from TEST where id = ${test}`;
```

But sometimes I have to add a `WHERE` Clause.

I tried this, but an error occurred.

```
let addwhere = `AND name = ${name}}`;
conn.query`select * from TEST where id = ${test} ${addwhere}`;
```

How do I dynamically add where conditions?

Comment: At least It seems you forgot to add one `{` in `${name}}` it should be `{${name}}`

Comment: And what package do you use to connect and execute queries against MS SQL?

Comment: If name is a string, it needs to be quoted. Even so, please note that you may be generating dangerous SQL subject to **SQL Injection attacks**. You should learn how to parameterize your queries to avoid concatenating possibly unsafe input data into the query statement itself.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822891/how-to-build-dynamic-query-by-binding-parameters-in-node-js-sql for some examples of using dynamic where clauses together with parameterized queries. (In short use "?" as placeholders and dynamically build up a matching array of values to pass into the execute query call.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I used 'mssql' module.
According to the document of the mssql module, quotation marks were not used even for strings.
Mysql uses '?' but mssql does not have that in the document.